# Is it possible to setup webform site to use windows authentication and azure ad authentication in the same time

Tags: asp.net, authentication, webforms, windows-authentication, azure-authentication

Is it possible to setup a webform site to use windows authentication and azure ad authentication at the same time?
We have an old asp.net webform site. We used windows authentication on it. We added the possibility to authenticate a user by Azure AD (we used  OWIN). The problem is we can setup only one type of authentication: windows or OWIN(azure ad), but we need both.
In the web.config I added:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="ccs_auth" loginUrl="sso.aspx" protection="All" path="/" timeout="45" cookieless="UseCookies"/>
    </authentication>
<location path="sso.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="?,*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

In the IIS I allowed "windows authentication" and "forms authentication"  for sso.aspx page. My idea is: when the user redirected to sso.aspx I get a login name from **System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"]**, then check this name in active directory, then try to find a user in our database. If the user not found, starts azure active directory authentication, if authenticated, we try to find a user in the database by Azure AD claim.
My code in Startup.cs :

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        if (useAzureAd)
        {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType("ApplicationCookie");
            //app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                AuthenticationType = "ApplicationCookie",
                LoginPath = new PathString("/sso.aspx"),
                CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.SameAsRequest
            });

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
              new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
              {
                  // Sets the ClientId, authority, RedirectUri as obtained from web.config
                  ClientId = clientId,
                  Authority = authority,
                  RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                  // PostLogoutRedirectUri is the page that users will be redirected to after sign-out. In this case, it is using the home page
                  PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
                  Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
                  // ResponseType is set to request the id_token - which contains basic information about the signed-in user
                  ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,
                  // ValidateIssuer set to false to allow personal and work accounts from any organization to sign in to your application
                  // To only allow users from a single organizations, set ValidateIssuer to true and 'tenant' setting in web.config to the tenant name
                  // To allow users from only a list of specific organizations, set ValidateIssuer to true and use ValidIssuers parameter 
                  TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                  {
                      ValidateIssuer = false
                  },
                  // OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications configures OWIN to send notification of failed authentications to OnAuthenticationFailed method
                  Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                  {
                      AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
                  }
              });
        }
 }
```

In result I get an exception:

```
HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found
The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long.
```

Look like my request is infinite redirects to the sso.aspx:

```
Requested URL
   http://localhost:80/AzureAdWebForm/SSO.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2FAzureAdWebForm%2FSSO.aspx%3FReturnUrl%3D%252FAzureAdWebForm%252FSSO.aspx%253FReturnUrl%253D%25252FAzureAdWebForm%25252FSSO.aspx%25253FReturnUrl%25253D%2525252FAzureAdWebForm%2525252FSSO.aspx%2525253FReturnUrl%2525253D%252525252FAzureAdWebForm%252525252FSSO.aspx%252525253FReturnUrl%252525253D%25252525252FAzureAdWebForm%25252525252FSSO.aspx%25252525253FReturnUrl%25252525253D%2525252525252FAzureAdWebForm%2525252525252FSSO.aspx........................
```

If I set useAzureAd = false, windows authentication works correctly.
If I set useAzureAd  = true and remove  `<authentication mode="Forms">` from config - Azure AD works correct

Where is my mistake? Is it possible to use both: windows authentication and Azure Ad in the webform web site?